# Incorrect sorrting by insert with forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array with objects. I want to import these into a sqlite3 database. I
do this with a forEach loop. It works well. But I wonder why the objects are not
imported in the order I put them into the database.

**This is what I do**

```js
const comments = [
  {post_id: 1, comment: "lorem ipsum comment 1", comment_author: "user 1"},
  {post_id: 2, comment: "lorem ipsum comment 2", comment_author: "user 1"},
]

comments.forEach(c => {
    sql = `INSERT INTO comments(post_id, comment, comment_author) VALUES (?,?,?)`
    db.run(sql, [c.post_id, c.comment, c.comment_author], (err) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err.message)};
    });
});
```

If I now execute a select, I get the following pure order *(take a look to post_id)*:

```js
[
  {id: 1, post_id: 2, comment: "lorem ipsum comment 2", comment_author: "user 1"},
  {id: 2, post_id: 1, comment: "lorem ipsum comment 1", comment_author: "user 1"}
]
```

**Question** Why is this happening? And what can I do to change the behavior.

**Expected result:**

```js
[
  {id: 1, post_id: 1, comment: "lorem ipsum comment 1", comment_author: "user 1"},
  {id: 2, post_id: 2, comment: "lorem ipsum comment 2", comment_author: "user 1"}
]
```

**Note** I Guess it has something to do with the async of javascript.

Comment: @sid `SELECT * FROM comments`. And `db.all("SQL *  FROM comments", [], errHandling)`

Comment: The fact that `id` appears to be out of sync makes me think the inserts are being processed asynchronously and that there's some race happening. s

Comment: what happens if you do `comments.reverse()` before `comments.forEach(..`? do you get any different results?

Comment: If it is a race issue, you may want to see if there's a bulk insert option to process all of these at once.

Comment: @AlanOmar Yes that was my first though but that is not a solution that is more a "dirty hack" and not what the SO asking. Hw would like to understand why it is. And agree that this is happened because it run async. To change this behavoir he must change to sync. For example with async await.

Answer (score 1):

You are right with your guess: `I Guess it has something to do with the async of javascript.`!

```js
let placeholders = comments.map((c) => '(?)').join(',');
let sql = 'INSERT INTO comments(post_id, comment, comment_author) VALUES ' + placeholders;

// output the INSERT statement
console.log(sql);

db.run(sql, [comments], (err, results, fields) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  // get inserted rows
  console.log('Row inserted:' + results.affectedRows);
});

// close the database connection
db.close();
```